# How would you debug on a real-time parallel processing system?

Tags: debugging, parallel-processing, real-time

In one of the interviews I was asked "How would you debug on a real-time parallel processing system". I personally haven't worked with real-time parallel processing system. 
Can anyone give me a brief idea about how does debugging work in real-time parallel processing system?

Comment: Description of real-time parallel processing: http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4006622/Debugging-real-time-multiprocessor-systems-Part-1

Comment: Debugging it: http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4006623/Debugging-real-time-multiprocessor-systems-Part-2